# Determine visible sections of a UITableView when sections have no rows

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am attempting to determine which sections are currently visible in my UITableView. However, sometimes my sections do not have rows and only display their section header. Is there a way to determine, maybe by using the section headers, which sections in my UITableView is currently being displayed? Asking for -(NSArray *)indexPathsForVisibleRows does not work to determine the section, because there are no actual rows that are visible, just the section headers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best I can come up with is to use contentOffset and frame.size to compute the visible rectangle and iterate over each section calling `rectForSection:` and see which ones intersect.  Something like:

```
-(NSIndexSet*)visibleSections
{
    NSMutableIndexSet*  indexSet = [NSMutableIndexSet new];
    CGRect              visible = self.tableView.bounds;

    for(NSInteger section = 0 ; section < [self numberOfSections])
    {
        CGRect          sectBounds = [self.tableView rectForSection:section];

        if(CGRectIntersectsRect(sectBounds, visible))
        {
            [indexSet addIndex:section];
        }
    }

    return indexSet;
}
```

Comment: This works great! The only tweak I made was using self.tableview.bounds instead of getting the frame and modifying it's origin.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the better idea :)

Answer (score 1):

Swift version

```
if let visibleRows = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows {
    let visibleSections = visibleRows.map({$0.section})
}
```

Comment: This doesnot work for expandable collapsable sections

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 versions od @David answer

```
func visibleSection() -> IndexSet {

        var indexSet: IndexSet = IndexSet()
        let visibleRect: CGRect = self.bounds

        for sectionIndex in 0..<self.numberOfSections {

            let sectionBounds = self.rect(forSection: sectionIndex)

            if sectionBounds.intersects(visibleRect) {

                indexSet.insert(sectionIndex)
            }
        }
        return indexSet
    }
```